# PHP array_map vs Python map with lambda

Tags: php, python, lambda, closures

I have a set in Python:

```
set = {list} [[['x']], [], [], []]
i = 1
j = 0
```

and this is my problem code:

```
set[i] += map(lambda x: [j] + x, set[i - 1])
```

after compute the line results in the following correct set:

```
set = {list} [[['x']], [[0, 'x']], [], []]
```

is it possible to create the same lambda function
anyhow with array_map and lambda in PHP ?

Any Ideas?

I tried this:

```
  $set[$i] = array_map(function ($s,$j) { return $j + $s; } , $set[$i - 1]);
```

But this won't work because the parameter $j isn't available inside the lambda

Comment: Please don't use map with lambdas. Use a list comprehension instead: `[[j] + x for x in set[i - 1]]` Also don't call a variable `set`, especially not if it's not an actual set (but even if it is: don't do it).

Comment: Hi, but that is not the question. I need the code in PHP btw also any other solution to come to the same results like the code in Python can do.

Comment: That's why I posted it as a comment...

Comment: Maybe you can give a workaround in Python, which is easier to translate to PHP?

Answer (score 1):

`$j` should not be a function parameter; instead, it should be a variable captured from the surrounding scope, something like:

```
$set[$i] = array_map(function ($s) use ($j) { return $j + $s; } , $set[$i - 1]);
```